# Why aren't neighbor patches centered at turtle location in NetLogo? Also when setting "targets" when at neighbors why is it not reciprocate?

Tags: netlogo

Using Netlogo: What I want is turtles to eat other turtles depending on their location (and later depending on their size). I have tried this code:

```
breed [cods cod]

cods-own [energy target]

to setup
  clear-all
  setup-patches
  setup-turtles
  reset-ticks
end

to setup-patches
  ask patches [set pcolor grey]
end

to setup-turtles
  create-cods number [
    set color blue
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set shape "fish"
    set energy 100
    if random 100 < 80 [ set size  12]
    if random 100 < 75 [set size  11]
    if random  100 < 70 [set size  10]
    if random  100 < 65 [set size  9]
    if random  100 < 60 [set size  8]
    if random  100 < 55 [set size  7]
    if random  100 < 50 [set size  6]
    if random  100 < 45 [set size  5]
    if random  100 < 35 [set size 4]
    if random  100 < 30 [set size  3]
    if random  100 < 25 [set size  2]
    if random  100 < 20 [set size  1]
  ]
end

to go
if not any? cods [stop]
ask turtles [wander
    wiggle
    move
    eat
  check-if-dead
  ]
  ask cods [set size size + growth-rate
  set energy energy - movement-cost]
tick
  my-update-plots
end

to wander
  ask cods [
    wiggle
    move
  ]
  ;; sheep procedure, the sheep moves which costs it energy

end

;; sheep procedure, the sheep changes its heading
to wiggle
;; turn right then left, so the average direction is straight ahead
right random 90
left random 90
end

to move
forward 1
end

;; sheep procedure, if my energy is low, I die
to check-if-dead
if energy < 0 [
die
]
end

to eat
  if any? turtles-on neighbors[
    ask neighbors [set pcolor green]
    set target one-of turtles-on neighbors ;with [ size <= [size] of myself - 1 ]
    create-link-with target [set color red]
    ask target [ set color red]
  ]
end
```

I set a target and set color red only so I can check what is happening, but they are supposed to eat each other. The thing is that when they set the target, if it based on "neighbors" and so on patch distance, I was expecting that given that the are reciprocate neihbors, both of the turtles would set red, but this is what I get:

[Only one is target, turtle not centered in neighbors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCd8q.png)

Which means two problems:

- Why is cod not centered in a neighbors?
- Why does only one of the turtles who are at the same distance set the target to the other one, and not be targets of each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that cod movement and eating take place in the same `ask` block in the `go` procedure.  Remember that in `ask` turtles are asked in random order to execute all the commands in the `ask`.  So, one cod will find another cod in it's neighborhood, create a link to it and turn it red.  But when the `ask` gets to that red cod, it has moved as a result of its own wandering, wiggling and moving, and it is thus no longer a neighbor.  Indeed, BOTH cod have moved.  As each cod executes the `ask` in the go procedure, it in turn asks all cod to wiggle and move in the `wander` procedure.  That is why you find that both original neighbor cod have moved out of the neighborhood.  If you take `eat` out of the `ask` in the `go` procedure and move it to a separate `ask` that is executed after all the movement has finished, you will find that you get the reciprocity you seek.

Two things to think about.  First, do you want each cod to ask all cods to wander, or just to wander itself?  Second, since all your turtles (at least so far) are cod, it might be clearer to use `cod` rather than `turtle` throughout.